# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{p_n^s} \right)=-\ln \zeta(s)$ the only known series with primes and nontrivial closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, closed-form, riemann-zeta

To clarify, I'm asking about series where $n$th term depends only on $n$th prime number. From the famous result (by Euler, I think) we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{p_n^s} \right)=-\ln \zeta(s)$$

As a particular case:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{p_n^2} \right)=-\ln \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

> What about the general series:
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(p_n)$$
>
> Does it have a nontrivial closed form for some other function $f$?

In general, I'm also interested in infinite products (they can be easily written as series, as I did for the titular one), nested radicals, continued fractions, etc.

---

**Edit**

Thanks to the great advice of @user1952009, I looked up [Dirichlet beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function), which has the prime expansion:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \ln \left(1-\frac{(-1)^{(p_n-1)/2}}{p_n^s} \right)=-\ln \beta(s)$$

Among it's special values we have:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \ln \left(1-\frac{(-1)^{(p_n-1)/2}}{p_n} \right)=-\ln \frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \ln \left(1-\frac{(-1)^{(p_n-1)/2}}{p_n^2} \right)=-\ln G$$

(Catalan's constant)

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \ln \left(1-\frac{(-1)^{(p_n-1)/2}}{p_n^3} \right)=-\ln \frac{\pi^3}{32}$$

Etc.

Comment: Now I'm curious about $$1+\cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{3+\cfrac1{5+\cfrac1{7+\dots}}}}$$

Comment: @SimpleArt, no closed form is known. Neither for the nested radical

Comment: Darn it, I tried.

Comment: I don't know if this counts, but Euler proved that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges.

Comment: I recall a long time ago proving a series involving primes in the exponent, i'm going to try dig it up, with some luck i might find it

Comment: do you know Dirichlet L-function ? they are a generalization of $\zeta(s)$ : $L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s}$ where $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character : it is completely multiplicative, meaning that $L(s,\chi) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-\chi(p) p^{-s}}$, and also $q$-periodic :  $\chi(n+q) = \chi(n)$ so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s}$ converges for $Re(s) > 0$ (when $\chi$ is not principal). Finally, if $\chi$ is primitive then its discrete Fourier transform is $\overline{\chi}$, so that $L(s,\chi)$ has a functional equation similar to $\zeta(s)$

Comment: @user1952009, that looks kind of artificial. Could you provide some examples? I wanted something like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{p_n^2} \right)=-\ln \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: @YuriyS what do you mean by artificial ? with the help of the $\chi$, you can compute for example $\sum_{p^k, p \ge 3} \frac{(-1)^{(p^k-1)/2} }{k p^k}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions  and an example is the [Drirchlet beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function)

Comment: @user1952009, the second link is relevant, thank you very much

Comment: almost everything you can do with $\zeta(s)$, you can do it with $L(s,\chi)$ too (in particular conjecturing the generalized Riemann hypothesis, probably the most important question related to the prime numbers)

Comment: @user1952009, thank you very much. The $\beta$ function is a gem, but I don't know anything more general so far.

Comment: Factorizations with prime numbers appear to be more common than summations (not counting if you log them)